# query that should delete records doesnt work (php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, records

I've been trying to delete a record in HTML/PHP but it didn't work and I've tried a lot. Does anyone know a solution for me?

```
 <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['project_id']; ?>Delete</a>

<?php
    }?>
```

And this is delete.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['titel'];


$sql = "DELETE FROM Projects where titel= '".$id."'";
if(mysqli_query($dbLink,$sql)){

    echo "<p>It is failed!</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<p>Deleting is succesful done!</p>";}

?>
```

Comment: Try and print mysqli_error() inside the else to see if any errors occured

Comment: You're using the wrong array variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `$_GET['titel'];` but what you're meant to get is `$_GET['id'];`

Either change it to `id`, or change your `a` link to:

```
<a href="delete.php?titel=<?php echo $row['project_id']; ?>Delete</a>
```

What you should do then, in your `delete.php` file, is change your `$sql` to:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Projects where id= '".$id."'";
```

Also ensure `$dbLink` is set in `delete.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below the updated code. Kindly use delete on particular row id as title or any other field may create some issue.

```
<a href="delete.php?project_id=<?php echo $row['project_id']; ?>Delete</a>

<?php
    }?>
```

And this is delete.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['project_id'];


$sql = "DELETE FROM Projects where project_id= '".$id."'";
if(mysqli_query($dbLink,$sql)){

    echo "<p>It is failed!</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<p>Deleting is succesful done!</p>";}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $_GET will not work as you are sending `id` in your query string. Try the following in `delete.php`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```